# Alamofire swift4 InvalidURL

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift4

Note: **Test Api Used**

I am using the latest 4.0 version of Alamofire with Swift4.0 and am trying to make a api request (GET) however what I get is a FAIULRE: INvalid URL

```
func getFlightData(airportCode: String, minutesBehind: String, minutesAhead:String){
    let securityToken: String = "Basic YWFnZTQxNDAxMjgwODYyNDk3NWFiYWNhZjlhNjZjMDRlMWY6ODYyYTk0NTFhYjliNGY1M2EwZWJiOWI2ZWQ1ZjYwOGM="

    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]
    headers["Authorization"] = securityToken

    var params: Parameters = [:]
    params["city"] = airportCode
    params["minutesBehind"] = minutesBehind
    params["minuteAhead"] = minutesAhead


    Alamofire.request("https://api.qa.alaskaair.com/1/airports/‬SEA/flights/flightInfo?city=SEA&minutesBehind=10&minutesAhead=120", method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
    }
```

The result I get is:

```
FAILURE: invalidURL("https://api.qa.alaskaair.com/1/airports/‬SEA/flights/flightInfo?city=SEA&minutesBehind=10&minutesAhead=120")
```

Do i need to encode my url? if yes then how? The same request works great with the URL provided by Alamofire documentation:

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode parameters like this:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["city": "SEA", "minutesBehind" : "10"] // Add all parameters

Alamofire.request("https://api.qa.alaskaair.com/1/airports/‬SEA/flights/flightInfo", parameters: parameters)
```

Comment: https://api.qa.alaskaair.com/1/airports/‬SEA/flights/flightInfo?city=SEA&minutesBehind=10&minutesAhead=120

Comment: Does the order of parameters get jumbled up?

Comment: Order should not matter.. You have a Unicode Character 'POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING' (U+202C) in your URL before SEA...

Comment: Try to copy-paste this url: https://api.qa.alaskaair.com/1/airports/SEA/flights/flightInfo

Comment: Yep that worked. How did you find out about that special charecter?

Comment: Got it! I see it too when I copy paste it...Thanks a ton man :)